# Issues with refreshing view for angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker Angular 6

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, angular-bootstrap

I have been using this date-time picker https://dalelotts.github.io/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/index.html and i am changing the configuration based on other selection the user makes, but after the first change the view remains the same(the date-time picker opens on the last view that was used before) even thought the configuration was properly changed. This is a sample of my code:

```
<dl-date-time-picker minView="{{minView}}"
                     startView="{{startView}}"
                     maxView="year"
                     minuteStep="5"
                     #datepicker
                     [class.weekView-display]="isWeekView"
                     (change)="setDisplayDate($event)"
                     (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
</dl-date-time-picker>
```

So, basically the minview and startView updates, but the user still sees the previous view.

Thank you

Comment: Try some debugging with ngDoCheck..

Comment: I did:  @ViewChild('datepicker') datePicker: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  ngDoCheck() {
  
    this.datePicker.startView = this.startView;
  } It seems to have my new value but the UI doesn't change its starting view

Comment: setDisplayDate($event) is the function that should update the data ?

Comment: that one is triggered when you selct a date i need the selected date to calculate some things in ts

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set `startView`.

`startView` is the view when the user first interacts with the date/time picker.

`minView` is the view when selection happens. Think if it as the last view.

From what you describe, I suspect you want to set `startView`, or perhaps both `startView` and `minView` to the same values.

You can see the the component does property respond to configuration changes by running the demo applocation https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-demo

The demo is also on StackBlitz but StackBlitz has a bug at the moment - https://stackblitz.com/github/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-demo